# Form(prefix=) and Race Conditions

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

As a small learning project, I am using `Form` prefix to submit two separate forms (same Model) as a one-page form. The model `Account` has a field `account_number` that increments after each model save. The initial value either 1 or user-defined.

My issue is that my `form2` doesn't receive the correct value. I have been trying to use `F() expressions` and `request_from_db()` but I'm not sure if I am implementing them properly.

I have tried using a call back on the default value in the account_number field (below) but I can see that the default account_number on Form2 is the same as Form1. It does change after saving, but If I open two browsers tabs of the form page before I submit the first page, the account_numbers aren't unique.

My Account model.py

```
def account_number_increment():
    last_number = Account.objects.all().order_by("account_number").last()
    if last_number:
        print("before db refresh", last_number.account_number)
        last_number.refresh_from_db()
        print("after db", last_number.account_number)
    start_from = AccountNumber.start_from
    acc_number = '1'
    if start_from:
        while Account.objects.all().filter(account_number=start_from).exists():
            acc_number_start = int(last_number.account_number) + 1
            print("acc # from start from", acc_number_start)
            return str(acc_number_start)
    if last_number:
        while Account.objects.all().filter(account_number=last_number.account_number).exists():
            new_acc_number = int(last_number.account_number) + 1
            print("acc # from last number", new_acc_number)
            return str(new_acc_number)
    if not last_number or not start_from:
        return acc_number


class Account(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=account_number_increment, blank=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

My forms.py

```
class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['name', 'account_number']
```

my views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = AccountForm(prefix='form1', data=request.POST)
        form2 = AccountForm(prefix='form2', data=request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            form2.save()            
            return redirect(reverse('users:users_home'))
    else:
        form1 = AccountForm(prefix='form1')
        form2 = AccountForm(prefix='form2')

    context = {
        'form1': form1,
        'form2': form2,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)
```

If I override the Model `save()` only form1 is saved. Not sure what happens to the other one, don't get any errors.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        last_number = Account.objects.all().order_by("account_number").last()
        if last_number:
           if self.account_number == last_number.account_number:
               print("FROM MODEL: before db refresh", last_number.account_number)
               last_number.refresh_from_db()
               #self.account_number = last_number.update(account_number=F('account_number') + 1)
               self.account_number = F('account_number') + 1
               self.save()
               print("FROM MODEL, after db refresh", last_number.account_number)
               super(Account, self).save(*args, kwargs)
        else:
            super(Account, self).save(*args, kwargs)
```

`Form(commit=False)` isn't working for me either. If I open two browsers tabs of the form page before I submit the first page, the account_numbers aren't unique.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = AccountForm(prefix='form1', data=request.POST)
        form2 = AccountForm(prefix='form2', data=request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()            
            form = form2.save(commit=False)
            last_number = Account.objects.all().order_by("account_number").last()
            if last_number:
                print("FROM VIEW: before db refresh", last_number.account_number)
                last_number.refresh_from_db()
                print("FROM VIEW, after db refresh", last_number.account_number)
            # acc_number_form1 = form1.cleaned_data['account_number']
            
            form.account_number = int(last_number.account_number) + 1
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('users:users_home'))
    else:
        form1 = AccountForm(prefix='form1')
        form2 = AccountForm(prefix='form2')

    context = {
        'form1': form1,
        'form2': form2,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)
```

I am assuming it needs to be done at the database level with F() and request_from_db()? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `refresh_from_db()` fetches the same object from the database again, it doesn't re-run the query. So `last_number.account_number` will be the same as before. Your `account_number` field has `unique=True`, so it shouldn't allow duplicate values if you have migrated the database properly.

Comment: If you're using postgres, you could create [a sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html) and use that to generate account numbers. One possible downsides is that you can end up with gaps (e.g. 1,2, 4,6,7) if you get the next id from the sequence but don't save the object.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you for the clarification about `refresh_from_db().` How would you suggest I get an incremented `account_number` to Form2? `pre_save` signal?